# Table top maze game

Tags: identify-this-game

In the 60s, we played a maze type game that used a round disk that was larger than a carrom that we hit with a cue stick. The game board was square and much larger than a carrom board. The play started on the outer part of the table and progressed around the board, eventually spiraling around to the center. There were wooden barriers that each player had to maneuver around or through and each corner had a small opening that had to be entered. There were numbered, painted areas that each player had to arrive at (in order). The object was to continue around the board while precisely hitting the disk to specific spots on the board and finally ending up in the center of the board.

Does anyone remember a game like this? Preferably with pictures.

Comment: This reminds me of [marble maze](http://g04.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1EYTyKpXXXXcaaXXXq6xXFXXXi/Labyrinth-Wooden-Pinball-Toy-font-b-Maze-b-font-Board-font-b-Marble-b-font-Game.jpg) though that's certainly not what you're looking for.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like the game I'm thinking of, but definitely not what's in the picture. Those girls look like kids in the 80's. I have specific memories, I think it was in elementary school, early 60s, going to another school during summer session. Played the game a lot. I don't know what made me start thinking of it, but as I started searching Google, came across this post. I recall actually being pretty good at the game. The carroms may have actually been plastic checkers pieces but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some digging it appears that the game you are looking for is "Castle Dungeon Maze" if you search for it in google it appears as you described however there could be variants of it. Hope this is what you are looking for!

[Here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/132183/desperately-seeking-game-1976-1977) is the original forum I found it on.

Also here is the picture I found:
[image]